# Unix command to find string set intersections or outliers?

Tags: unix, grep, set

Is there a UNIX command on par with

```
sort | uniq
```

to find string set intersections or "outliers".

An example application: I have a list of html templates, some of them have {% load i18n %} string inside, others don't. I want to know which files don't.

**edit:** grep -L solves above problem.

How about this:

file1:

```
mom
dad
bob
```

file2:

```
dad
```

%intersect file1 file2

```
dad
```

%left-unique file1 file2

```
mom
bob
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It appears that `grep -L` solves the real problem of the poster, but for the actual question asked, finding the intersection of two sets of strings, you might want to look into the "comm" command.  For example, if `file1` and `file2` each contain a sorted list of words, one word per line, then

```
$ comm -12 file1 file2
```

will produce the words common to both files.  More generally, given sorted input files `file1` and `file2`, the command

```
$ comm file1 file2
```

produces three columns of output

1. lines only in file1
2. lines only in file2
3. lines in both file1 and file2

You can suppress the column `N` in the output with the `-N` option.  So, the command above, `comm -12 file1 file2`, suppresses columns 1 and 2, leaving only the words common to both files.

Comment: Don't forget to run your files through sort before the comparison. I did, and the results sent me on a wild goose chase.

Comment: I do mention above that each file contains a "sorted list of words", but it might not jump right out at you.

Answer (score 9):

Intersect:

```
# sort file1 file2 | uniq -d
dad
```

Left unique:

```
# sort file1 file2 | uniq -u
bob
mom
```

Comment: The intersect works, but left unique does not. It shows the unique values across the whole set, not those uniquely in the first.

Answer (score 7):

From http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5710/intersection-between-two-files:

Intersection between two (unsorted) files:

```
grep -Fx -f file1 file2
```

Lines in file2 that are not in file1:

```
grep -Fxv -f file1 file2
```

Explanation:

- The `-f` option tells grep to read the patterns to look for from a file. That means that it performs a search of file2 for each line in file1.
- The `-F` option tells grep to see the search terms as fixed strings, and not as patterns, so that `a.c` will only match `a.c` and not `abc`,
- The `-x` option tells grep to do whole line searches, so that "foo" in file1 won't match "foobar" in file2.
- By default, grep will show only the matching lines, giving you the intersection. The `-v` option tells grep to only show *non-matching* lines, giving you the lines that are unique to  file2.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but why not just use grep to look for the string (use the -L option to have it print the names of files that don't have the string in them).

In other words

```
grep -L "{% load i18n %}" file1 file2 file3 ... etc
```

or with wildcards for the file names as appropriate.

Comment: For faster searching, I'd use -F too, since it's just a fixed string.

Comment: what about set intersections?

Answer (score 2):

from man `grep`

```
-L, --files-without-match
```

> Suppress normal output; instead print
>   the name of each input file from which
>   no output would normally have been
>   printed.  The scanning will stop on
>   the first match.

So if your templates are .html files you want:

```
grep -L '{% load i18n %}' *.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Intersection:

```
comm -12 <(cat file1 | sort | uniq) <(cat file2 | sort | uniq)
```

All lines by 3 columns (file1 | file2 | intersection):

```
comm <(cat file1 | sort | uniq) <(cat file2 | sort | uniq)
```

If your files are not sorted and/or if there might be lines that are duplicated inside one of the files but don't appear at the other one - this one-line-command will sort your files, remove the duplicated lines and you will get directly your desired result.